# Azure Virtual network gateway being used for an excess number of hours

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network-gateway

I primary needed a way to securely access and SSH into VMs that are inside a V-NET in azure without exposing the VMs to a public IP.

I setup a Azure Virtual network gateway with a Point-to-Site configuration. I basically used this video as a guide to setup the VPN on a windows computer. https://youtu.be/Gb3YE-0gBWQ

My understanding what that I would only get charged for the number of hours I am connected to this VPN. In a month I barely connect to the VPN for an hour. However, according to azure support, this has been connected for 744 hours with a month. I am on a minimal plan and have been changed an inconsistent amount between $20 to $60 for the past few months.

How are these hours calculated? If there was a consistent charge for all months, I would assume the charge is on a monthly basis. However, that is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [VPN Gateway pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/vpn-gateway/), the charge is calculated considering the amount of time that the gateway is provisioned and available, not the time you spent with an active VPN:

> Setting up a virtual network is free of charge. However, we do charge for the VPN gateway that connects to on-premises and other virtual networks in Azure. This charge is based on the amount of time that gateway is provisioned and available.

Doing some maths: 31 days * 24 hours = 744 hours (the hours you have been charged)...